# Bootstrap progress bar with tooltip as legend

Tags: progress-bar, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I have created a bootstrap toolbar with multiple sections in different styles. Now I want to add a tooltip that serves as a legend, explaining what the different styles stand for. But the styles do not appear inside the tooltip. Is this possible at all? How can I make this work?

Here a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/xdg5b7ys/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="progress" style="width:300px" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-html="true" title="<div class='text-start'><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar bg-success opacity-50' role='progressbar' style='width: 100%' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'></div></div>Gebudgetteerd: 800<br><div class='text-start'><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar bg-success' style='width: 100%' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'></div></div>Definitief: 327.79<br><div class='text-start'><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar-striped bg-success' style='width: 100%' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'></div></div>Proef: 118.52</div>">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 40.97375%" aria-valuenow="40.97375" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar-striped bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 14.815000000000001%" aria-valuenow="14.815000000000001" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success opacity-50" role="progressbar" style="width: 44.21125%" aria-valuenow="44.21125" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Initialize tooltips
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I see:
[image]

I would expect the progress bars in the tooltip to have the style I've set on them but they just appear gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `style` attribute is not applied, because it's being removed [by the sanitizer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer), so the bar element has no width, so no background is applied.

Only these attributes are allowed for `div`:

> // Global attributes allowed on
> any supplied element below.
> '*': ['class', 'dir', 'id', 'lang',
> 'role', ARIA_ATTRIBUTE_PATTERN],

So, use Bootstrap's size utility class [`w-100`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/sizing/) to add width instead of `style` attribute:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="progress" style="width:300px" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-html="true" title="<div class='text-start'><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar bg-success opacity-50 w-100' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'></div></div>Gebudgetteerd: 800<br><div class='text-start'><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar bg-success w-100' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'></div></div>Definitief: 327.79<br><div class='text-start'><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar-striped bg-success w-100' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'></div></div>Proef: 118.52</div>">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 40.97375%" aria-valuenow="40.97375" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar-striped bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 14.815000000000001%" aria-valuenow="14.815000000000001" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success opacity-50" role="progressbar" style="width: 44.21125%" aria-valuenow="44.21125" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Initialize tooltips
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or you can disable sanitizer or add your custom sanitizer via `sanitize` and `sanitizeFn` [options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#options)

For example, your HTML will work if you disable sanitizer:

```
return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {sanitize:false})
```